# Unable to locate table element using xpath in selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

I have to select a row on the webpage using selenium and my code is unable to locate the element using xpath. To do that I used the xpath of the checkbox and tried to click it. This is my code.

```
#driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[18]/td[1]/input").click()
    chk= driver.find_element_by_id("/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[18]/td[2]")
    chk.click()
    
#chck= driver.find_element_by_xpath("html body.nifty-ready div#container.effect div.boxed div#content-container.frame-container div.page-content")
```

And I'm getting the error:

```
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-7c151851b480> in <module>()
     66 
     67 #driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[18]/td[1]/input").click()
---> 68 chk= driver.find_element_by_id("/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[18]/td[2]")
     69 chk.click()
     70 

NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[18]/td[2]"]
```

Please suggest a better way to do this.

Comment: Why are you calling .find_element_by_id with an xpath?

Comment: As pointed out by @JustinEzequiel, replace ```.find_element_by_id``` with ```.find_element_by_xpath``` and it should work fine.

Comment: Selecting by id was a typo. I'm using xpath only. But xpath doesn't work, css selector is still working. Still I have to go further into the nested divs and select the drop down menu

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine.

```
chk = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[18]/td[2]")
chk.click()
    
chck = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("html body.nifty-ready div#container.effect div.boxed div#content-container.frame-container div.page-content")
```

Comment: It will be useful if you read the [documentation.](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Comment: chck = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("html body.nifty-ready div#container.effect div.boxed div#content-container.frame-container div.page-content div:nth-child(3) div.pad-all div")
chck.click()

I'm trying to access this element using css selector but it doesn't go further than div.page-content. I wan't to open the drop down menu and it's selector path is this-  
#content-container > div.page-content > div:nth-child(3) > div.pad-all > div > button

Comment: I get this error:

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"html body.nifty-ready div#container.effect div.boxed div#content-container.frame-container div.page-content div.panel div.pad-all"}
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.193)

Comment: Ah, if it is a dropdown then you would want to wait sometime before finding the nested elements so that they are available in DOM. Use ```time.sleep(2)``` or  selenium ```EC``` after clicking on the dropdown and before finding the nested element.